# Not able to access service from app component in Angular2

Tags: angular

This is the **data.ts** class where I have defined the variables of the object I want to access:

```
export class Data {
  id : number;
  name : string;
}
```

Then my **mock-data.ts** class where I am returning a hardcoded array of objects:

```
import { Data } from './data';
import { Http,Headers,RequestOptions } from  '@angular/http';

export const DATAS : Data[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

console.log(DATAS);
```

My **my-service.ts** class where I am returning a Promise object of type Data[].(Till here I am getting back my object fine)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Headers,RequestOptions } from  '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DATAS } from '../../app/mock-data';
import { Data } from '../../app/data';

/*
  Generated class for the MyServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class MyServiceProvider {

  DATAS : Data[];

  openWebMwthod() : Promise<Data[]>{

    console.log("Here data is",DATAS);
    return Promise.resolve(DATAS);

  }

}
```

But, in the last step where I am calling the service from my **app.component.ts** file, I am getting object undefined:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy  } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
//import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MyServiceProvider } from '../providers/my-service/my-service';
import { Http,Headers,RequestOptions } from  '@angular/http';
import { Data } from './data';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp implements OnInit{
  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  datas : Data[];


  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private myServiceProvider : MyServiceProvider) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

    });
  }

 getData() : any{
   //console.log("Calling web service");
   this.myServiceProvider.openWebMwthod().then(datas => this.datas = datas);
   console.log("obj is",this.datas);
 }

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.getData();
     console.log("Debo data:",this.getData());

  }

}
```

Can someone tell where I might be possibly going wrong?

Comment: Please always include your code as code blocks in question instead of pictures. Some people might want to debug your code and also most likely refer to your code in their answer, no one is going to write all that code long hand ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `DATAS` class param in your service class which gets initialised with `undefined` value. You are imptorting the right `DATAS` object from your mock object, but I think it might get overriden.

BTW, your `console.log` line 34 in the component might be logging way before the `Promise` is resolved, as promise resolution is async. Therefore you should do your logging in the `then` method to see what value gets resolved in the promise.

BTW v2, another `console.log` line 39 is not logging anything as `getData` is not returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working solution:

**app.component.ts(excerpt)**

```
 ngOnInit(){
     this.myServiceProvider.openWebMwthod()
         .subscribe((response)=>{
            this.datas = response;
            console.log("here Inside app component",this.datas);
            alert("here Inside app component"+this.datas);
        });   

  }
```

**my-service.ts(excerpt)**

```
openWebMwthod() : Observable<any>{


    let headers = new Headers(
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',    
        }
      );

    let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});

    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',options)
             .map( (res) => res.json())


  }
```